# Jenkinsfile - Post action avoid code duplication for statuses

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins pipeline to run a build.

How can I avoid code duplication for 2 post statuses that execute the same code (failure & unstable)?

example code snippet:

```
  post {
  failure
  {
    emailext(
    attachmentsPattern: '**/log.txt', 
    body: "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}", 
    subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", 
    to: "test@test.gmail"
    )
  }
  unstable
  {
    emailext(
    attachmentsPattern: '**/log.txt', 
    body: "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}", 
    subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", 
    to: "test@test.gmail"
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function and use it, f.e.

```
 post {
  failure
  {
    sendMail()
  }
  unstable
  {
    sendMail()
  }

  def sendMail() {
    emailext(
    attachmentsPattern: '**/log.txt', 
    body: "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}", 
    subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", 
    to: "test@test.gmail"
    )
  }
```

Comment: Don't use [notify](http://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify) since it is an already reserved key in java! The pipeline will throw a compile error. So just rename the method to e.g. sendEmail() Also I used void instead of def for the return method signature